# Can a user sign in to a firebase app by logging in to another app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, authentication, electron

I have an electron app and electron apps don't allow firebase auth by default.
Therefore, what I want is that I'll develop a web app which will be hosted on a server.
User will open the corresponding URL and will login there via firebase auth.
Now I want that user should copy something like ID token or Refresh token and should paste in the electron app and he/she should get logged in there too.
Is it possible?
If yes, then how? any example please?
As much as I researched, I found out that firebase ID tokens do expire  within a short duration let's say 1 hour.
And there's no way to get the refresh token.
Please help me, I'm struggling with this since many days and my app development is obstructed due to this.
If this is not possible, then please guide me that what should I do?

Comment: Have you already given a look at this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-firebase it provides Firebase authentication in Electron

Comment: yes bro @Gregorio Palamà I looked at it. but it doesn't suit my needs as it is a complete framework and my application is already developed and is based on electronforge. This package changes the file and directory structure too which I don't want